# How to promote an answer from a comment?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, comments, moderator-tools

I've seen in an unanswered question that an user posted what seems to be an answer as a [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/samsung-galaxy-s2-upgraded-to-ice-cream-sandwich-now-bluetooth-headphones-wont#comment26285_22496). That user has not posted it as an answer although someone suggested him to do so (maybe he has not logged in since then so he is not aware of this). It has passed more than a year after that comment, and no one has answered the question. There are probably people who are going through the same situation described in this question, but seeing that there is still no answer they desist to clicking on it, likely ignoring the comment with which the user gave the right answer to his own question.

A simple solution would be to copy and paste the comment as my own answer, winning reputation at the expense of someone else's effort, but exactly that makes it an **unethical** action.

My question is: is there any way that one of the moderators would **promote** that comment to the category of **answer**, without user intervention needed, so that the user who made the comment gets all the credit (reputation) for having answered correctly the question, as it should be?

Answer (score 4):

If it is just a copy-paste from a single comment, I usually do that and make it a Community Wiki. I fully agree with you, we should not adorn ourselves with borrowed plumes :)

I however skip the Community Wiki part if I combine an answer from multiple comments while adding some more details (or point out connections/background). In that context, I don't feel it unethical to win reputation, as I put some real effort in my post.

Comment: Exactly, that is the case of another question which I just answered (the "Alicia Han" incident), trying to give context to what others commented and what I myself researched.

Comment: Then it's perfectly right you eran some rep on it, IMHO. Btw: Did Alicia call you as well? #D